# Comparing a column value of a dataframe with another dataframe in day wise level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two Dataframes

```
   Box      box_cap     size      Preference
    1          16       1200           1
    2          16       1550           2
    3          15       1300           3
```

Another one is

```
   Day  Capacity
    1        23
    2        24
```

I need the following dataframe as an output

```
   Day  Box     box_cap
    1    1          16
    1    2           7
    2    2           9
    2    3          15
```

It is basically day wise allocation of the ball numbers as per the day wise capacity. Preference number is used to put the box in sequential manner. As box 1 has 1st preference, then box 1 will go first. I am trying to do it using as per the following

```
for i in df.index:
    tun = df['Tundish'][i]
    heat = df['Heat'][i]
    width = df['Width'][i]
    pref = df['Preference'][i]
    tuntobegiven = []
    for j in dfday.index:
        day = dfday['Day'][j]
        cap = dfday['Capacity'][j]
        caps = cap - heat
        if caps >= 0:
            tuntobegiven.append((tun, day))
```

Unable to crack it. The data is dummy. There can be multiple number of boxes.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the easiest is to use an iterative code, optionally with numba to enhance performance:

```
from numba import jit

def allocate(df, dfday):
    @jit(nopython=True) # optional
    def compute(boxes, capacities):
        box_idx = 0
        cap_idx = 0
        out = []
        while (cap_idx < len(capacities)) and (box_idx < len(boxes)):
            take = min(boxes[box_idx], capacities[cap_idx])
            boxes[box_idx] -= take
            capacities[cap_idx] -= take
            out.append((cap_idx, box_idx, take))
            if not capacities[cap_idx]:
                cap_idx += 1
            if not boxes[box_idx]:
                box_idx += 1
        return out
            
    # ensure inputs are sorted by Preference/Day        
    df = df.sort_values(by='Preference', ignore_index=True)
    dfday = dfday.sort_values(by='Day', ignore_index=True)
    
    # run allocation
    out = pd.DataFrame(compute(df['box_cap'].to_numpy(copy=True),
                               dfday['Capacity'].to_numpy(copy=True)),
                       columns=['Day', 'Box', 'box_cap'])
    # convert indices to actual values
    out['Day'] = dfday['Day'].to_numpy()[out['Day']]
    out['Box'] = df['Box'].to_numpy()[out['Box']]

    return out

out = allocate(df, dfday)
```

Output:

```
   Day  Box  box_cap
0    1    1       16
1    1    2        7
2    2    2        9
3    2    3       15
```